# Using JMeter for availability testing

Tags: jmeter

My goal is to fire a thread every 15 minutes to a website with some actions (e.g. intro, choose_language, search_term). Where I will assert using a Response Assertion to check whether the site is available.

Is it possible to schedule JMeter like this from within JMeter itself? Is it possible using any of the timers? I am thinking of starting my script using the Windows Scheduler as a plan B.

I thought I would be able to set it with the Ramp-Up in the Thread Group. My thought was:

*Number of Threads (users): 1*
*Ramp-Up Period (in seconds): 60*

that this would mean that 1 user would be started every 60 seconds, but this seems not to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want,
You can use one user, and within a debug sampler at end of (login, intro, search) add a timer that last 15 minutes.

You misunderstand rampup, with what you set it's useless as there is only 1 user. With 15 users, it means, start each of these 15 users within 60 minutes then once started it is not used anymore

Comment: This works and thanks for clarifying the ramp up. Ideal situation would be that I can schedule to start a test on exactly 15:15 or 15:30 pm. Is that also possible?

Comment: Thought the reward of accepted answer was enough a bonus :-) That scheduler is just to start and end. Can't set any recurrence... So no that's not an option.

Comment: Do you intend to start JMeter once for all and schedule within JMeter (which seems weird to me in this case as if you run every 15 minutes, why schedule ?) ? I think external schedule through Cron or Windows scheduler might be better.